# Finding html element with custom field in XML response using groovy

Tags: html, xml, groovy, soapui

In SOAP UIs XML Response I have an element like below:

```
<option selected="selected" value="5">Premium</option>
```

i am tryin to find the element with a custom field value in the XML response.
 Get the value "selected" of 'selected' attribute of element with value="5" and text= Premium.

i am doing something like below. But it returns me a [] response.

```
def sortByValue= resp.depthFirst().option.findAll{it.@selected=="selected" && it.text()=='Premium'}
log.info sortByValue
```

while

```
 def sortByValue= resp.depthFirst().option.findAll{it.@value=="5" && it.text()=='Premium'}
log.info sortByValue
```

returns me a response

```
  [option[attributes={value=5}; value=[Premium]]]
```

I am unable to get the value of selected

Could someone please let me know how to make this work ?

Comment: Examples I've seen put the "@" and the attribute name in single quotes, like "it.'@value'". However, that doesn't explain why the "value" reference seems to work, but the "selected" reference does not.  It almost seems like it's not seeing the XML that you think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to this would suffice?

```
def xml = '''\
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Regular</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="5">Premium</option>
        <option value="7">Gold</option>    
    </select>
</div>
'''

def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
parsed.'**'.option.findAll { 
    it.'@selected' == 'selected' && it.text() == 'Premium' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... :)

```
 def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

        def holder =  groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("TestStepName#Response")
        def optionNode = holder.getDomNode("//option")
        def optionNodeAttributes = optionNode.getAttributes()

        log.info optionNodeAttributes.getNamedItem("selected").getNodeValue()
        log.info optionNodeAttributes.getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue()
        log.info holder.getNodeValue("//option")
```